# Using jar libraries without Eclipse

Tags: android, jar

I have created my project using `android create project`. I have my own code in `package com.notreal` under `src/notreal/`. According to just about everywhere, all I have to do is to put the library into `libs/`

The library I'm trying to use is Google's Gson library. I have downloaded a `.zip` which expanded to a directory with couple of `.jar` files. I moved the whole directory into `libs/` and am including `com.google.json` in my source.

The issue is that it can't see the library. I get `error: package com.google.json` does not exist. I have tried everything I could find, from using `ant -lib lib debug`, `and -lib libs`, doing the both with all the `.jar` files straight in `libs/`.

Quite literally every single answer out there assumes that one is using Eclipse. I am not using Eclipse so please don't post how to do it with Eclipse.

Lib here - http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/detail?name=google-gson-2.2.2-release.zip

`ls libs/` - `gson-2.2.2.jar  gson-2.2.2-javadoc.jar  gson-2.2.2-sources.jar`

Comment: Please post a link to the specific GSON download that you are using. Also, I suggest posting a screenshot or something showing the current state of your `libs/` directory. What should work is just having the two JARs *directly* in `libs/` (no subdirectories, no other files).

Comment: I updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `gson-2.2.2-javadoc.jar` and `gson-2.2.2-sources.jar` files, as they are not JAR files containing compiled Java code. From there, you should be OK:

```
package com.example.asdfasd;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Gson g=new Gson();
  }
}
```

With just `gson-2.2.2.jar` in `libs/`, this compiles from the command line and Eclipse without issue.

Comment: Oh yes, it compiles~ Thanks, you just saved by Hackathon!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the classpath for javac in ant. Then the compiler can see the library.

```
<javac ...>
  <classpath>
    <pathelement location="lib/"/>
    <pathelement path=".../"/>
  </classpath>
</javac>
```